# typescript HTMLSelectElement options value should declared as HTMLOptionsCollection

Tags: select, typescript, html-select

Current the HTMLSelectElement interface declare
  options: HTMLSelectElement;

which seems wrong. It is supposed to be options: HTMLOptionsCollection

it would also be useful to have selectedOptions declared as HTMLCollection

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question. For bugs, you can submit an issue on [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript), or better yet, submit a pull request with the fix.

Comment: OK, will shift to github.

Comment: This appears to be the issue in GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1558